# Unit test, try to trigger ngOnchange methods Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, onchange

I'm trying to test this function here :

```js
ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.isCustomer) {
      let sectionCopy = [...this.sections];
      this.sectionsNotFilled = sectionCopy.find(section => section.filled === false);
...
    }
}
```

I saw on a lot of  ressource that in order to trigger ngOnChanges, I have to use `fixture.detectChanges();`, but i still can not test  and got the wrong result on my test:

```js
...
let component: XXX;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<XXX>;
...
const sections = [
  {
    key: 'SECTION1',
    name: 'Section 1',
    filled: true
  },
  {
    key: 'SECTION2',
    name: 'Section 2',
    filled: false
  }
];

...

it('should do test', () => {
    const sectionsMock = {...sections};
    component.sections = sectionsMock;
    component.isCustomer = true;

    console.log(component.sections); => section are here
    //trigger

    fixture.detectChanges();

    console.log(component.sectionsNotFilled);

    expect(component.sectionsNotFilled).toBe(true); => return false :/
  });
```

Any ideas? Did I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting to an old thread. Most likely my answer is no longer relevant for the PO, but hopefully, it will be helpful for other people who have a similar question.

I managed to get `ngOnChanges` respond to `fixture.detectChanges` by reconfiguring the `testBed` before each test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: ...,
      providers: ...,
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Will be happy to hear out if there are better solutions.

Answer (score -2):

The `ngOnChanges` gets triggered on the ***first*** `fixture.detectChanges()` and not subsequent ones.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(XXX);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  const sectionsMock = {...sections};
  component.sections = sectionsMock;
  component.isCustomer = true; // set isCustomer = true here
  fixture.detectChanges(); // call fixture.detectChanges() here to go to ngOnChanges()
                           // and the line above will ensure that it goes inside of the if block

});

it('should do test', () => {
  expect(component.sectionsNotFilled).toBeTruthy(); // I think you need toBeTruthy() here
                                                    // because I think sectionsNotFilled resolves into an object.
});
```

Comment: It don't change the result, As I trigger only one time the fixture detect change

Comment: Interesting. I guess `ngOnChanges` gets called only in unit tests only if we explicitly call it or we wrap the component in a host component and feed in the inputs. https://medium.com/@christophkrautz/testing-ngonchanges-in-angular-components-bbb3b4650ee8